# LINQ Join with Multiple Conditions in On Clause

Tags: linq, join

I'm trying to implement a query in LINQ that uses a left outer join with multiple conditions in the ON clause.

I'll use the example of the following two tables *Project* (ProjectID, ProjectName) and *Task* (TaskID, ProjectID, TaskName, Completed). I want to see the full list of all projects with their respective tasks, but only those tasks that are completed.

I cannot use a filter for `Completed == true` because that will filter out any projects that do not have completed tasks. Instead I want to add `Completed == true` to the ON clause of the join so that the full list of projects will be shown, but only completed tasks will be shown. Projects with no completed tasks will show a single row with a null value for Task.

Here's the foundation of the query.

```
from t1 in Projects
join t2 in Tasks
on new { t1.ProjectID} equals new { t2.ProjectID } into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { t1.ProjectName, t2.TaskName }
```

How do I add `&& t2.Completed == true` to the on clause?

I can't seem to find any LINQ documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50463823/314291) using Lambda syntax

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You just need to name the anonymous property the same on both sides

```
on new { t1.ProjectID, SecondProperty = true } equals 
   new { t2.ProjectID, SecondProperty = t2.Completed } into j1
```

Based on the comments of @svick, here is another implementation that might make more sense:

```
from t1 in Projects
from t2 in Tasks.Where(x => t1.ProjectID == x.ProjectID && x.Completed == true)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { t1.ProjectName, t2.TaskName }
```

Comment: That seems like a non obvious way to do that. I'm not sure I would understand what it's suppose to do.

Comment: @svick - Using anonymous types allow you to join on multiple criteria. You just need to make sure the property names match on both types. Not sure where the confusion is coming from?

Comment: The confusion is that it really makes more sense as two equalities joined by `and`, not one equality of some “weird” object. And to prove my point, your code is wrong. For it work, you would have to have `true` on the left side and `t2.Complete` on the right.

Comment: Thanks Aducci. I had to swap sides in the query to get the context right, but that worked. This problem is simplified, and in my real world problem it's not just SecondProperty is true or false, SecondProperty is an integer and I use `AND SecondProperty IN (123, 456)`. I'll be moving on to that challenge and any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @svick - Good catch, I switched the order of the *t2.Completed* and the *true* value. I added another solution that might be less weird for you.

Comment: @Kuyenda - Look at my second solution: you can change *x.Completed == true* to *listOfIntergers.Contains(x.Completed)*

Comment: Yup, just noticing this. Working it right now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Aducci - The latter solution is still a left outer join by virtue of `DefaultIfEmpty` correct? My example was set up to be easily grouped because I join into j1, and then after `from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()` I added `group j2 by`. How would I group your latter example? Thanks again!

Comment: @Kuyenda Here you can see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495439/linq-join-with-in-condition-in-on-clause

Answer (score 67):

Here you go with:

```
from b in _dbContext.Burden 
join bl in _dbContext.BurdenLookups on
new { Organization_Type = b.Organization_Type_ID, Cost_Type = b.Cost_Type_ID } equals
new { Organization_Type = bl.Organization_Type_ID, Cost_Type = bl.Cost_Type_ID }
```

Comment: This looks more understandable.

Comment: This helped with Compiler Error CS1941.  Matching the name the anonymous types

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. The `join` clause (and the `Join()` extension method) supports only equijoins. That's also the reason, why it uses `equals` and not `==`. And even if you could do something like that, it wouldn't work, because `join` is an inner join, not outer join.

Comment: Outer join was not requested, and (see other answers), obviously you can.