# LINQ LEFT JOIN to another LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, left-join

I am pretty green with LINQ and brand new to converting LEFT JOINs.
I wrote a query in SQL (which works fine) and I am trying to get it into LINQ.  I am missing something, but can't see it.  The SQL is:

```
DECLARE @Version int = 1
SELECT Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID, Lay.*
FROM WebFormTemplates WFT
INNER JOIN WebFormTemplateQuestions Q ON Q.WebFormTemplateID = WFT.WebFormTemplateID
LEFT JOIN WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaders Hdr ON Hdr.WebFormTemplateID = WFT.WebFormTemplateID and hdr.Version = @Version
LEFT JOIN WebFormTemplateLayouts Lay ON Lay.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID = Hdr.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID AND Lay.WebFormTemplateQuestionID = Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID
WHERE WFT.WebFormTemplateID = 2 
ORDER BY Q.SortOrder
```

The LINQ I wrote is:

```
    Version = 1
    Dim q3 = From WFT In ctx.WebFormTemplates
        Join Q In ctx.WebFormTemplateQuestions On Q.WebFormTemplateID Equals WFT.WebFormTemplateID
        Group Join Hdr In ctx.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaders On Hdr.WebFormTemplateID Equals WFT.WebFormTemplateID Into Hdr_join = Group
            From Hdr In Hdr_join.Where(Function(x) x.Version = Version).DefaultIfEmpty()
        Group Join Lay In ctx.WebFormTemplateLayouts On Lay.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID Equals Hdr.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID And Lay.WebFormTemplateQuestionID Equals Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID Into Lay_join = Group
            From Lay In Lay_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Where WFT.WebFormTemplateID = 2
```

With this, I can break the code and in the immediate window get the expected values when I type:

```
?q3.FirstOrDefault().Hdr.Version
```

But for the Lay item I need to type:

```
?q3.FirstOrDefault().Lay.FirstOrDefault().QuestionAlign
```

to get the value.
Why do I need to call FirstOrDefault the second time?  What am I missing here?
When I do a Select, the values are all null for Lay I assume because I don't have another FirstOrDefault someplace.  Everything from Hdr, WFT, and Q work just fine.  Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: You have a 2-D array x(,).  FirstOrDefault gets index zero an array or returns nothing (an empty item).  You need it twice once for each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

i have written your equivalent Linq query from the SQL in C#.
Update accordingly for VB.

```
Version = 1
    Dim q3 = (from WFT In ctx.WebFormTemplates
        join Q In ctx.WebFormTemplateQuestions on Q.WebFormTemplateID equals WFT.WebFormTemplateID
        join Hdr In ctx.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaders on Hdr.WebFormTemplateID equals WFT.WebFormTemplateID into Hdr_join 
        from Hdr In Hdr_join.Where(Function(x) x.Version = Version).DefaultIfEmpty()
        join Lay In ctx.WebFormTemplateLayouts on new { Lay.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID,Lay.WebFormTemplateQuestionID } equals new {Hdr.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID, Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID}  into Lay_join
         from Lay In Lay_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         where WFT.WebFormTemplateID = 2
         select new {Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID, Lay});
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I tried converting that line to what I believe is the VB equivalent, ( Join Lay In ctx.WebFormTemplateLayouts On New With {Lay.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID, Lay.WebFormTemplateQuestionID} Equals New With {Hdr.WebFormTemplateLayoutHeaderID, Q.WebFormTemplateQuestionID} Into Lay_join) but it didn't work.  I added the word "group" in front which got rid of some of the errors, but still no go.  I also tried variations of New with no luck.

Comment: you need to match the type of the properties used in new {K=1} equals new {K=1}, here both K proerty are Int type.
[Follow more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664727/linq-join-with-multiple-conditions-in-on-clause)