# LINQ Join with multiple or conditions

Tags: c#, linq, join

My question is mostly similar to this question [LINQ Join with Multiple Conditions in On Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7664727/8373489) and most other similar question which either talk about having properties to specifically map the respective conditions or writing a query without join like

```
from t1 in Projects
from t2 in Tasks.Where(x => t1.ProjectID == x.ProjectID && x.Completed == true)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { t1.ProjectName, t2.TaskName }
```

Suppose if I go for the first way of writing i.e.

```
on new { t1.ProjectID, SecondProperty = true } equals 
   new { t2.ProjectID, SecondProperty = t2.Completed } into j1
```

that gets converted to AND (&&). I want an OR (||) in the join form (2nd way of writing).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LINQ supports only equi-joins. For all other types you should use `Where` (i.e. no join) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform the join by the `ProjectID` and then have an `||` on the `SecondProperty` then you must join by one field and add a `where` clause:

```
from t1 in Projects
join t2 in Tasks on t1.ProjectID equals t2.ProjectID
where t1.SecondProperty || t1.SecondProperty == t2.Completed
select new { t1, t2 }
```