# LinQ Join with Multiple Conditions in On Clause WITH LAMBDA SYNTAX

Tags: linq, join, lambda

I have seen several SO posts explaining how to write a LinQ Join with an additional join condition on top of the key equality.
For instance this one :
[LINQ Join with Multiple Conditions in On Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664727/linq-join-with-multiple-conditions-in-on-clause)

Is it possible to write this in lambda syntax? If so how?

Comment: could you give an example on what you mean with additional join condition? I'm not sure, if you are referring to a complex key that is not a primitive type or something different.

Comment: something like the " Completed == true " in the example

Comment: So you just want to have a complex object as keys.