# LINQ Join with "IN" Condition in "On" Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

Related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664789/2327332). And also I found something [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/139199ae-a463-4c69-a053-47dadf1d44d9/linq-how-to-write-multiple-conditions-for-quotonquot-clause?forum=aspdatasourcecontrols)

I have this scenario:

My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [tbl1] t1
LEFT JOIN [tbl2] t2 ON t1.IdX = t2.IdX AND t2.IdY IN (1,4)
```

I tried to translate into this LINQ:

```
var query = from t1 in tbl1
        join t2 in tbl2 on new{ idx = t1.IdX, idy = new byte[] { 1, 4 } } equals new{ idx = t2.IdX, idy = adresa.Idy } into tbl3
        from t3 in tbl3.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But the problem is here `new byte[] { 1, 4 }`.

Is any solution to this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Try : join t2 in tbl2.Where(x => (x.Udy == 1 ) || (x.Udy == 4 ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join also can be performed by `SelectMany` operator. Check documentation for that [Complex Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators)

```cs
var query = 
    from t1 in tbl1
    from t2 in tbl2
        .Where(t2 => t1.Idx == t2.Idx && new byte[] { 1, 4 }.Contains(t2.Idy))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { t1, t2 };
```